# Playing with a chess cipher

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, chess, checkerboard

Alice and Bob both love encryption, and Alice loves to play chess. Unfortunately, Bob isn't very good at chess, so he doesn't think it's very fair to have to play the game for real. So instead of playing chess, Alice and Bob decided to turn chess into their very own chess cipher. Once they had agreed to a scheme Alice sent the following test message to Bob.

```
1.  Nf3  d6 
2.  Nc3  b5 
3.  Ne4  h6 
4.  Nxd6 Kd7
5.  Nxf7 a6
6.  Nd6  h5
7.  Nxb5 axb5
8.  g4   e5
9.  Nxe5 Ke8
10. gxh5 b4
11. c3   bxc3
12. b4   Nd7
13. b5   Nxe5
14. d3   Nc4
15. dxc4 c6
16. Bg5  cxb5
17. Be7  Qxe7
```

So what message did Alice send?

**Hint 1**

> There are three steps needed to reach the final solution. Figure out which cipher they are using; determine the constraints, if any; determine how the chess moves fit into the chosen cipher to create a plain text answer.

**Hint 2**

> The content of the framing story offers a hint to the specific cipher that they use. Once you know the cipher, some of the chess moves will provide the rest of the information you need.

**Hint 3 (a bit of big one)**

> Chess is a bit like a boxing match, the fighters always start in one of the corners. From there, a lot of the moves are just posturing, but it's the hits that make contact that people come to see.

Comment: One can view the game described [here](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_d6_Nc3_b5_Ne4_h6_Nxd6*_Kd7_Nxf7_a6_Nd6_h5_Nxb5_axb5_g4_e5_Nxe5*_Ke8_gxh5_b4_c3_bxc3_b4_Nd7_b5_Nxe5_d3_Nc4_dxc4_c6_Bg5_cxb5_Be7_Qxe7).

Comment: I thought bob was an expert in logic

Comment: I'm so sad this isn't a 8x8 Playfair cipher using ASCII Range 64-127 xD

Comment: @LukasRotter Chess is more of a traditional kind of game

Comment: Probably a coincidence, but is Alice/Bob interested in a certain type of music? Most of the game might just be fluff if that were the case, but I have to ask :)

Comment: @LukasRotter Not related to music, but most of the game is fluff. Or rather, setting it up for the parts of the game that are important to the cipher.

Comment: rot13: Fb, vg'f qrsvavgryl n 5k5 Cynlsnve pvcure, naq gur xrl zbirf ner gur barf va juvpu fbzrguvat vf orvat pncgherq. Ohg V pna'g sbe gur yvsr bs zr svther bhg jung gur xrl zvtug or, naq gur fgevatf bs yrggref v'z gelvat (sbe rknzcyr, AQ AS AO NO AR TU OP AR QP PO DR) V'z abg svaqvat nal qrpelcgvbaf sbe rira jvgu oehgr sbepvat. Nz V ba gur evtug genpx?

Comment: @kristinalustig You are on the right track. rot13(Yvxr n wvtfnj, fgneg jvgu n pbeare cvrpr. Tb sebz rvtug gb svir, jurer'f gur pbeare?)

Comment: @kristinalustig rot13(Ab arrq gb qrpbqr, gur cynlsnve tvirf lbh gur cynva grkg qverpgyl.)

Comment: Gotta be honest - I'm totally lost. I rot13(qerj bhg gjb qvntenzf - bar jvgu whfg gur cynprf jvgu na K naq bar jvgu erpgnatyrf nebhaq gur zbirf jurer bar cvrpr gbbx nabgure. Abar bs gubfr ner svir ol svir. Jura V fcyvg vg hc ol cynlre, gur erfhygf-bayl sbe gur frpbaq cynlre vf, ohg gung fgvyy vfa'g rabhtu vasbezngvba. V qba'g haqrefgnaq lbhe zbfg erprag uvag V qba'g guvax, orpnhfr sebz rvtug gb svir vf bayl sbhe ebjf, abg svir.)

Comment: @kristinalustig rot13(Gur svefg zbir jvyy gryy lbh bar bs gur sbhe pbearef bs gur 5k5 fdhner fb lbh pna nffvta gur cebcre yrggref. Bar znex unccraf bhgfvqr gur 5k5 fdhner; fbyir gur erfg bs gur zrffntr gura frr vs lbh pna qrgrezvar gur fvtavsvpnapr bs gung.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is

> HELLO WORLD

because

> Map the following 5x5 grid onto the board:
>  [image]
>  The first move by white tells us the bottom right corner of the grid.
>  Then for each capture, take the underlying letter. One capture is outside the square, which represents a space
>  As hinted in the story, the 5x5 grid layout used is the same as in the Playfair cipher, even though we don't actually en/decrypt using playfair.

Notes / feedback:

> Since the concept is fairly simple, it may be surprising this was only solved now with a load of hints in the comments. I can only tell you the reasons I couldn't solve it sooner:
> - I picked up on the Playfair hint right aways, but assumed for the whole time until a comment that we actually had to decrypt using playfair. So I spent most of the time trying to figure out what's the key and what's the plaintext, and what custom variations could've been used (possibly more than one 5x5 grid, or a 8x8 ASCII grid). Maybe a hint only pointing towards a 5x5 grid would've been clearer.
> - After the boxing hints, I actually thought about mapping a 5x5 grid onto it and only counting captures, but since at least one move was out of bounds of any 5x5 grid, I ditched it without even trying. That may have been stupidity on my part, since using an out-of-bounds capture as a space is not a bad idea.
> - The thing that did it for me was the comment that the first move tells you the corner of a 5x5 grid and that one of the moves is out-of-bounds by design.

Comment: Yup, and thanks for providing the notes. It's hard to judge difficulty and I'm still trying to refine my puzzle making abilities, so those notes really help a lot. I do realize now the problem with the cipher, I actually didn't realize how it was more typically used